# PETREL Updating values in Zone Log. Processing Speed VERY SLOW

Tags: performance, logging, zone, petrel

A PETREL question
I created a new Attribute called "Over Pressure" in a set of Formation TOPS. I then created a Zone Log for this Attribute, to display in a well section. I am manually inputting values for Over Pressure into the Zone Spreadsheet for specific Zones and wells. But when I Apply the changes PETREL takes over an hour to perform the process. What is driving this excessive time. Too many wells ? Too many Zones ? .. is this a PETREL issue or an IT /Data Management problem with connection speeds etc etc etc.. ANY SUGESTIONS THANKS

I have tried to deleting unwanted wells, but this does not appear to help.